# I need help setting my y-axis properly so my data points aren't linear in my scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have year on the x-axis and a set of numbers on my y-axis. If you look at the chart, it ascends into infinity. But if you look on the y-axis the numbers are not sorted.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_csv('arrest_py.csv')

data = data.dropna(axis='rows')


year = data['YEAR']
total = data['TOTAL']


fig = plt.figure() # an empty figure w/ no axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # a figure with a single axis 
plt.scatter(year, total)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqaxj.png)

I simply want to create scatterplot. Idk what I am doing wrong. It could be how 'YEAR' is defined or something else. I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your data points are strings. convert the column to numeric